# How to read a program inputs from bash script

Tags: bash, input, command-line, fortran

I use bash script to compile and run a program. When the program is running it asks for some input data. How can I make the bash script give the inputs to the program so that I don't do it manually on the screen.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/csh

gfortran -o 1coupled AMAIN_C.FOR
mv 1coupled ./chemi
cd ./chemi
./1coupled
```

When the program runs it asks for the name of the program, and I have to enter it from the command line. I want to make it read it from the bash script.

thank you

Comment: It isn't a bash script, it's a csh script.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change to bash. `#!/bin/bash`
2. write the values you want it to read into a file.
3. redirect standard input from the file

   ./1coupled < file_of_values

or, read the man page "man 3f getarg" to learn more about retrieving command line args.

The following comes from: [the documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.1/gfortran/GETARG.html).

```
PROGRAM test_getarg
        INTEGER :: i
        CHARACTER(len=32) :: arg

        DO i = 1, iargc()
          CALL getarg(i, arg)
          WRITE (*,*) arg
        END DO
      END PROGRAM
```

Answer (score 0):

I mostly agree with @bmargulies, except that the function is using a f77 extension of gfortran, and should be avoided.

Current fortran has a standard way of accessing command line argument, named `GET_COMMAND_ARGUMENT`.

Check [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/GET_005fCOMMAND_005fARGUMENT.html).